# Warning:(55, 56) `withFilter' method does not yet exist on MoldPiece[PressureData(Int, prettyprint.YesNo)], using `filter' method instead

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

Is there a method for switching off that warning? I completely understand what it says, why it is generally helpful and why `WithFilter` exists, but this particular monad is used to compose individual functions rather than collections of monadic type values, and `WithFilter` won't provide any meaningful improvement while requiring an additional method and classes confounding the simple interface of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about defining `def withFilter(f: A => Boolean) = filter(f)` and documenting it only exists for this purpose? Unfortunately, Scala compiler doesn't have a general way to switch off warnings you don't want and I don't think there is a way specific to this one.

Comment: Well, I think it is 'good enough' for practical purposes. It just disturbs my aesthetic sense, marring otherwise cleaned up and minimalistic code. Maybe if I just move this declaration to a new base trait `Monad` and pretend the latter exists as a self-documenting way of describing what is the actual monadic type as it offen differs from the type parameter of the monad class... If nobody comes up with some other declarative solution I'll accept your answer as the best one.